# undefined symbol using pybind11 cmd

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pybind11, pybinding

i want to use pybind11 to create .so , my code contains this header

```
`#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "nvbufsurface.h"`
```

when i use :

> c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC  `python3-config --cflags --ldflags` -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pybind11/include  -I/home/xxx/deepstream_sdk_v4.0.2_x86_64/sources/includes  `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0,opencv`      -L/home/xxx/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/lib/  -lnvbufsurface -lcudart  -lnvdsgst_meta -lnvds_meta -lnvdsgst_helper  `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0,opencv`   example.cpp -o example.so

or i use:

> c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC    `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0` -L/home/xxx/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/lib   -lnvbufsurface -lnvdsgst_meta -lnvds_meta -lnvdsgst_helper    -lm    -I/home/xxx/deepstream_sdk_v4.0.2_x86_64/sources/includes   `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0`   `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`

and i import example in python3 i get undefined symbol: NvBufSurfaceSyncForDevice
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those linker flags should come *after* the cpp that needs them. I separated your code into different lines for readability.

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC  \
`pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0` \
-I/home/xxx/deepstream_sdk_v4.0.2_x86_64/sources/includes \
`python3 -m pybind11 --includes` \
example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix` \
`pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0` \
-L/home/xxx/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/lib -lnvbufsurface -lnvdsgst_meta \
-lnvds_meta -lnvdsgst_helper \
-lm
```