# ImportError: undefined symbol when linking pybind11 with a static/shared library

Tags: static-linking, dynamic-linking, pybind11

I tried to link pybind11 with a static library. The building process was successful, but I got the runtime error "ImportError: undefined symbol". Directly linking with `.o` file worked fine though.

I have no luck with shared libraries either, with the same error. For shared libraries, I moved `libadd.so` to `/usr/lib`.

An example with a static library is as follows:

```cpp
/* my_add.cpp */
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "add.hpp"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_add, m) {
    m.def("add", &add);
}
```

```cpp
/* add.hpp */
int add(int x, int y);
```

```cpp
/* add.cpp */
#include "add.hpp"

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

First, I complied `add.cpp` into a static library.

```bash
g++ -c add.cpp -o add.o
ar rcs libadd.a add.o
```

Then, I complied `my_add.cpp` and linked it against `libadd.a`.

```bash
g++ -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) libadd.a my_add.cpp -o my_add$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

In the same directory:

```
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /working_directory/my_add.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Z3addii
```

On the other hand, if I built with

```bash
g++ -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) add.o my_add.cpp -o my_add$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

then everything worked fine.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [undefined symbol using pybind11 cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475813/undefined-symbol-using-pybind11-cmd)

This is not really a `pybind11`-specific problem but a C/C++ problem.

> All those linker flags should come after the cpp that needs them.

In my case, swapping "libadd.a" and "my_add.cpp" solves the issue.

My question can be marked as a duplication. Thanks.